# Fully detach ChildProcess in Rust on Windows

Tags: process, rust, daemon

I need to relaunch a Rust application on Windows as administrator so I worked out a command that would do that for me.

After relaunching, I would like the initiating process to exit and the child to continue running. However, when the parent exits, the child exits too, which is undesired behavior in this case.

I have used the standard `process:Command` to launch the command (simplified here):

```
#![allow(unused)]
fn main() {
    use std::process::Command;
    use std::os::windows::io::IntoRawHandle;

    let mut mycom = Command::new("C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe")
        .arg("/C powershell -Command Start-Process -Verb runas -File-Path C:\\my\\file");
    let child = mycom.spawn()
        .expect("command failed to start");

    //Perfectly running Child dies after pressing Enter
    let mut s = String::new();
    std::io::stdin().read_line(&mut s);
}
```

I found some documentation of `.detached()` and `child.forget()` [here](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/15641) and [here](https://mail.mozilla.org/pipermail/rust-dev/2014-July/010789.html), however these options seem to be discontinued.

I also tried the Windows `start` command which also did not give me a detached process.

It's relatively easy on Linux by using `nohup` or `mycommand &`.
There may be a way with `setsid` in libc, but I didn't find any usable documentation for that, just [the generated documentation](https://docs.rs/libc/0.2.43/libc/fn.setsid.html).

Is there a way to achieve a fully detached process?

Comment: @Shepmaster Could it have something to do with [this](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/866a713258915e6cbb212d135f751a6a8c9e1c0a/src/libstd/sys/windows/process.rs#L81) and [this](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/866a713258915e6cbb212d135f751a6a8c9e1c0a/src/libstd/sys/windows/process.rs#L112) part of `process::Command`?

Comment: "However, when the parent exits, the child exits too, which is undesired behavior in this case." Are you sure ? Generally, child doesn't die with their parent, at least this is the standard behavior on all unix system, I didn't think windows differ.

Comment: But if you need special behavior I suppose your could directly use winapi with [`into_raw_handle()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/os/windows/io/trait.IntoRawHandle.html)

Comment: Also your use of `arg()` is incorrect, it's probably why your child die. You must use it as [doc](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Command.html#method.arg) say.

Comment: And for finish, try to avoid the use of `exit()`, the [doc](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/fn.exit.html) explain why.

Comment: I tried to implement all your suggestions, see my updated post, sadly the beahaviour is still the same. as for the `arg()`. Technically, I'm passing one long argument to `cmd.exe`, so it should be correct? - as the docs say to use one `arg()` per argument.

Comment: No, it's not correct this will problably not work, you doc is clear, you must do something like that: `.args(&["/C", "powershell", "-Command", "Start-Process", "-Verb", "runas", "-File-Path", "C:\\my\\file"]);`. And `into_raw_handle()` is not magic, this give you the raw handle of your os, aka windows in your case, you need to search, maybe [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/freeconsole) will work.

Comment: Ok, I'm now using `args` as I probably should with the same effect. I'm now trying to use `kernel32::StartProcessW` directly with the detach flags. Will update one that is done.

Comment: After using `winapi::um::processthreadsapi::CreateProcessW` directly, still with the same results, I checked other factors. It turned out that the "problem" was that the application was launched in a powershell which caused this behavior. If the program is launched directly, it works as expected. I'm unsure why this is the case, but it works now and the issue does not seem to be related to rust (I would have to test if e.g. C++ behaves the same way...). Thank you for your help!